# How to replace scipy.misc.imresize with Pillow in my example?

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I read up some threads about `scipy.misc.imresize` being removed in early versions, and how you have to use Pillow instead. The following is my line of code which is producing the error.

```
image_gray_resized = scipy.misc.imresize(arr=image_gray, size=fraction, interp='bicubic')
```

In the examples I saw, the Pillow version of this statement uses only two parameters, unlike mine which uses three. I don't know how I must change this to make it work in Pillow, because I have no clue how the parameters in

```
scipy.misc.imresize(*args, **kwds)
```

and the Pillow version

```
numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize())
```

are related. And more importantly how my own 3-parameter `imresize` fits into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check an old documentation page of [`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html):

- `arr` is the image itself as a NumPy array.
- `size` can be

  - an `int` (indicating some percentage),
  - a `float` (indicating some fraction, that's your example), or
  - a `tuple` (indicating a destination size).
- `interp` is the interpolation method to use.

Now, let's check, what [`PIL.Image.resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) is capable of:

- `size` must be a `tuple`. So, you'd need to determine the destination size beforehand when using a percentage or fraction as given above.
- `resample` is the resampling filter, which is basically the interpolation method as given above.

That's all we need to know to derive proper code:

```py
from imageio import imread      # scipy.misc.imread is deprecated
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image           # scipy.misc.imresize is deprecated

# Read image, get width and height
img = imread('path/to/your/image.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
print(img.shape)
# (241, 300, 3)

# Fraction as float
fraction = 0.2
img_resized = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((int(fraction * w),
                                                    int(fraction * h)),
                                                   Image.BICUBIC))
print(img_resized.shape)
# (48, 60, 3)

# Percentage as integer
percentage = 20
img_resized = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((int(percentage / 100 * w),
                                                    int(percentage / 100 * h)),
                                                   Image.BICUBIC))
print(img_resized.shape)
# (48, 60, 3)

# Size as tuple
size = (60, 48)
img_resized = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize(size, Image.BICUBIC))
print(img_resized.shape)
# (48, 60, 3)
```

The example shows, how to handle the three different ways of scaling (percentage, fraction, destination size). For a different interpolation method, you'd just need to map from `nearest` to `PIL.Image.NEAREST`, and so on.

---

**EDIT:** Just for further explanation: [`PIL.Image.fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) converts the input NumPy array to a Pillow [`PIL.Image.Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) object, such that you can use `PIL.Image.resize` at all.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
imageio:       2.9.0
NumPy:         1.20.2
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: One doubt @HansHirse. In the last method, where you resize it as a tuple, does the statement
size(60,48) 
make the image 60 pixels by 48 pixels or is it something else? And also, would it work if I read the image using imageio and did not obtain its original dimensions as W and H?

Comment: Pillow uses a `(width, height)` tuple, whereas - due to the (default) row-major ordering of NumPy arrays - `shape` returns `(height, width, channels)`. Thus, all three presented ways generate the same image with `(60, 48)` with `(width, height)`. When using percentages or fractions for resizing, you must calculate the destination size. Therefore, you somehow need the original dimensions. Either you use `shape` on the NumPy array, or you use [`width`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.width) and `height` on the `Image` object.

Comment: I see, so that's why.